# What is the meaning of $scope is hierarchical in nature?

Tags: angularjs

In learning about AngularJS, it is stated that:

> `$scope` is hierarchical in nature and follows the DOM structure of your angular application.

What does this mean?

Comment: Did my answer make more sense @Beginner?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the `$scope` object used by views in AngularJS is organized into a hierarchy with a root scope, which has one or more child scopes, similar to how the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) works.

That is sort of confusing wording to describe what they mean, but this page breaks it down pretty well: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes